# How to get the array that text belongs in

Tags: java, arrays, regex

I have a multidimensional array as follows:

```
[[Acid Exposure (pH),  Upright], [Recumbent, Total], [,  Upright Normal Recumbent Normal Total], [Normal],]
[[Bolus Exposure (Impedance)Upright], [,  Recumbent, Total], [,  Upright Normal Recumbent Normal Total], [Normal]]
[[Postprandial Data], [,  Postprandial Interval:  120 min]]
```

I want to create a new Array if the inner array contains the line "Acid Exposure (pH)" so that I end up with just `[Acid Exposure (pH),  Upright], [Recumbent, Total], [,  Upright Normal Recumbent Normal Total], [Normal],]` in a new array.

I tried this:

```
 ArrayList<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Acid Exposure \\(pH\\)");

     for (List<String> row:twoDim) {
         for (String cell:row){
            if (p.matcher(cell).matches()) {
              matches.add(cell);
             System.out.println(matches);
            }
     }
 }
```

but it just gave me `[Acid Exposure (pH)]`

Comment: well, you just check one value, and only add one. You might want to set a flag if you found a match, and once you found a match, add the whole `List` after the inner loop.

Comment: How do I do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just checking if you had a match in the `List` and only add this one specific item. You rather want to set a flag and add the whole `List` after you found a  match. Untested, but it should look like this:

```
// Just a hint, define matches a List to be able to change the actuall class of the List more easy.
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Acid Exposure \\(pH\\)");
for (List<String> row : twoDim) {
    boolean found = false;
    for (String cell : row) {
        if (p.matcher(cell).matches()) {
            System.out.println(matches);
            found = true;
            // Break out of the loop, no need to check for matches anymore
            break;
        }
    }
    if (found) {
        matches.addAll(row);
    }
}
```

Comment: OK. But this gives me [Acid Exposure (pH),  Total] rather than the array that this array is part of which is [Acid Exposure (pH),  Upright], [Recumbent, Total], [,  Upright Normal Recumbent Normal Total], [Normal]

Comment: @SebastianZeki then try adding `twoDim` instead of `row`.

Comment: Had to change  ArrayList<ArrayList> matches = new ArrayList<ArrayList>(); Not entirely sure why this worked, but it did.

Comment: @SebastianZeki it looks like you are trying to represent 3 Dimension (just from the example input), so, judging your example input and output, what you are trying to add is a `List<List<String>>`, That´s why you have define matches like this.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

You are just printing out the matched cell in the code and what you need is the entire row.

Why don't you modify the type of 'matches' and add the row you want to the matches.

Comment: Because I get an error which asks me to cast argument row to CharSequence on the line  if (p.matcher(row).matches()) {

Comment: Thats not what I meant. (p.matcher(cell).matches())  to check for the match. But when it matches, what you got to add to the matches list is not "cell" but the row. You might need to change the type of  List<String> matches, to store rows.

Comment: I mean matches.add(row); You can further polish the code so that, the same row won't be added more than once, if the row has more than one matches of the regex.

Answer (score 0):

You wanted to add an entire row but added only cell.

Change

```
matches.add(cell);
```

to

```
matches.addAll(row)
```

Comment: And then break the cell loop to not add the same row twice in case two different cells match.

Answer (score 0):

```
int find = 0;

    ArrayList<String> newarray = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i=0; i < initialArray.size();i++)
    {

        String[][] row = (String[][]) initialArray.get(i);

        for(int k = 0; k < row.length; k++ )
        {
            for(int l=0; l < row[0].length; l++)
            {
                if (row[k][l].equals("Acid Exposure (pH)"))
                {

                    find = i;
                    for(int p =0; p < row[k].length; p++)
                    {
                        newarray.add(row[k][p]);
                    }
                    break;


                }
            }
        }           
    }
```